# Solve for $x$: $\sum_{r=0}^5 {5\choose r} (-1)^rx^{5-r}3^r = 32$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-theorem

> Solve for $x$: $$\sum_{r=0}^5 {5\choose r} (-1)^rx^{5-r}3^r = 32$$

Looks like binomial theorem. So this would simplify to $(-x+3)^5=32$, and solving gives $x=2$. Is this correct?

Comment: close but it's not $(-x+3)^5$ but $(x-3)^5$, can you tell me why?

Comment: Oh oops, because it is to the same power as the 3...

Comment: There you go. we can merge the $(-1)^r(3)^r$ into $(-3)^r$. So what does that equal instead?

Comment: $(x-3)^5\!\!\!$

Comment: I was more or less asking what the solution was since you know that $(x-3)^5=32$. Sorry for being ambiguous.

Comment: $x=5\!\!\!\;\;$